# Powershell script to verify if files in a directory contain passwords

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script that downloads packages to audit them. I want to check if any of the .txt, .json or .config files are storing passwords or usernames. (which they should not).

I am searching the files using the Get-ChildItem function. A file like below is what I would be searching through. I need to clarify if its a placeholder or if there is an actual password stored in the file.

I need to come up with a way to see if the Username or Password contain values or if its just a place holder.
I have unzipped the package and getting the items from the unzipped location

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $unzipLocation
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName

    foreach ($file in $files) {

#Search unzipped file to see if they store a password
$content = Get-Childitem $unzipLocation -Include *.json, *.txt, *.config -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "password", "pwd", "user", "usr"
```

The content returns where Username or Password is located in a file:
[image]

The next line in the script will be to verify if the file contains a value in the Password field.

The file looks like:

```
{
"info": {
    "_postman_id": "70134a48-94c1-45ac-a1f0-4b84ccc7e71c",
    "name": "Analytical Report API tests",
    "schema": ""
},
"item": [
    {
        "name": "1. Login using test user",
        "event": [
            {
                "listen": "test",
                "script": {
                    "exec": [
                        "var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                        "pm.collectionVariables.set(\"token\", jsonData.access_token);\r",
                        "\r",
                        "pm.test(\"Login test\", () => {\r",
                        "    pm.response.to.have.status(201);\r",
                        "});"
                    ],
                    "type": "text/javascript"
                }
            }
        ],
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "header": [
                {
                    "key": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/json"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "mode": "raw",
                "raw": "{\n    \"partnerCode\": \"{{partner}}\",\n    \"password\": \"{{password}}\",\n    \"userName\": \"{{userName}}\"\n}"
            },
            "url": {
                "raw": "{{authBaseUrl}}/api/v1/Users/token",
                "host": [
                    "{{authBaseUrl}}"
                ],
                "path": [
                    "api",
                    "v1",
                    "Users",
                    "token"
                ]
            }
        },
        "response": []
"variable": [
    {
        "key": "token",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "currentARCode",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "currentAR",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "authBaseUrl",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "arBaseUrl",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "fromNumberOfDaysFilter",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "userName",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "password",
        "value": ""
    },
```

Is there a regex function I can use to verify this?

Comment: So, using `Select-String` like that, would give you a `MatchInfo` object and you could reference and be able to inspect the matched `password` with something like this: `$content.where({$_.Pattern -eq 'password'}).Line` but i'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, and this also assumes that the line has the exact word: "password" in it.

Comment: Then, using `$matches` is not a good idea, this is an automatic variable, it cannot be populated by you manually.

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon, I have edited above code a little. What is the best solution to verify the password field contains a password?

Comment: do all your files look like the one on the screenshot? but can have pwd / password and usr / user?

Comment: Yes correct they do

Comment: Can you put the file as plain text?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, copy paste the text as literal and add it to your question

Comment: I have added the contents of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is overly complicated but I don't see an easier way of doing it. It should be able to capture both, files with **pwd or password** and **usr or username**, in addition it should capture files that have one or the other, i.e.: password is there but no user (see `Index 4`).

To see the `regex` details: https://regex101.com/r/IsHg8O/1

```
$re = [regex]'(?msi)(pwd|password).*?\{\{(.*?)\}\}|(usr|username).*?\{\{(.*?)\}\}'

Get-Childitem $unzipLocation -Include *.json, *.txt, *.config -Recurse |
ForEach-Object -Begin { $z = 0 } -Process {
    $match = $re.Matches((Get-Content $_ -Raw))
    foreach($i in $match)
    {
        if($group = $i.Groups.Where({$_.Success}))
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Index = $z
                Match = $group[1].Value
                Value = $group[2].Value
                Path  = $_.FullName
            }
        }
    }
    $z++    
}
```

**Sample**

```
Index Match    Value            Path
----- -----    -----            ----
    0 password password         /home/user/json1.txt
    0 userName userName         /home/user/json1.txt
    1 pwd      d]5!bT8**<\fcaY? /home/user/json2.txt
    1 usr      example.user1    /home/user/json2.txt
    2 password h+Rq~%d7kQ_\ew%] /home/user/json3.txt
    2 usr      example.user2    /home/user/json3.txt
    3 pwd      Y4)8-SnkVYZ>=wKn /home/user/json4.txt
    3 username example.user3    /home/user/json4.txt
    4 pwd      ,;F3QV(3~JB)grM{ /home/user/json5.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is json(doesnt matter if its in text file) then you can directly use `convertfrom-json` instead of regex. I just took the same which can be used as below:

```
$a = @'
    [   
        {
            "authBaseUrl": "#{AuthAPIServerURL}",
            "arBaseUrl": "#{APIServerURL}",
            "partner": "EUPLKA",
            "fromNumberOfDaysFilter": 90,
            "password": "",
            "userName": ""
        }
    ]
'@
    
    $inp= ConvertFrom-Json $a
    
    If( ($inp.username.trim().Length -gt 0) -or ($inp.password.trim().Length -gt 0) ) 
    {
    echo "yes - either the username or the password field is having value"
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "false- None of the username of password field is having any value"
    }
```

Note: Make sure that while taking the input, the declaration in array must be on the beginning of the line. I have considered the length of the username and password field but you can have your own regex to see if there is any character.